# Sap Abap Hierarchial report editing a column

Tags: abap, alv

Working on a program which I display an ALV report. Hereby  in the ALV toolbar I have a button in order to display header info and when it's pressed it displays item info. When I want to go back, (BACK BUTTON) it does not sends me to selection screen, but it goes to the last call (where I've used the button) and thats incorrect. I've configured the back button correctly but it doesnt works. 
Any help ?

Comment: Just post some code of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Set description of button in gui-status

[image: gui]
and also don't forget about PAI modul that makes something that you want

[image: PAI]

It should help you. Good luck!